# GREF does not decrease

Tags: xamarin.forms, telerik

I am using Xamarin form to develop a app.
From the logger I saw a lot of log like GREF has increase to XXXX and finally app stopped at 2000.

I used Telerik Xamarin form TabView.
I just keep switching the tab and the GREF keep increasing. (One change add 100GREF). for the tab content, there is a tableview inside and displaying text.

What should I do to debug/fix?